# Trac: Changesets lost after changing SVN repository path

Tags: svn, trac

Last evening I did some housekeeping on our code repository - basically moved the code from /repo/trunk to /repo/projectname/trunk.

I changed the repo path on my trac.ini - after which trac complained the repository needed to be resynced. So I ran:

```
trac-admin /var/trac/projectname resync
```

and all was well.

Then I checked the changesets against the ticket and found that trac no longer has a link to show the code against changesets - says "No changeset XXX in repository".

Has anyone here had the same issue they managed to solve? I need the broken links to the changeset fixed.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like you did:

```
svn mv <repobaseurl>/trunk <repobaseurl>/projectname/trunk
```

Then changed `trac.ini` from

```
repository_dir = /path/to/repo
```

to

```
repository_dir = /path/to/repo/projectname
```

What you have done is to point Trac at a *subset* of your repository... namely, only the changesets that affect the `projectname` subdirectory of the repository.  This is generally referred to as a "scoped" repository.

You have a couple of choices:

1. You can change the `repository_dir` back to what it was and you will see all your changesets, and will see the history going back across your reorg.  Simple fix.
2. You can use `svndumptool.py` to retroactively move all your changesets to have always been under projectname instead of the root of the repository and leave repository_dir as you have it.  Harder fix, may not even be what you want.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed explanation. I pointed it back to my old repo path and it's back to working fine.